# html form not transferring data to google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, forms

Hi I have been following this tutorial [submit data from html forms to google sheets](https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175)
The ajax code is as follows:

```
var $form = $('form#test-form'),
  url =
```

'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwoNkRscUxkp7bOdHx3pPwj4D2doLATbgqEYKOoaIRFXCdRPlM/exec'

```
$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(
// do something
    );
  })
```

The problem I am getting is that the data is not transferring over to the google spreadsheet.  Below is the html code.

```
<form id="test-form">

<div>
  <label>Field 1</label>
  <input type="text" name="Groceries" placeholder="Field 1"/>
 </div>

 <div>
   <label>Field 2</label>
   <input type="text" name="Diary" placeholder="Field 2"/>
 </div>

  <div>
    <label>Field 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="Meat" placeholder="Field 3"/>
  </div>

<div>
  <label>Field 4</label>
  <input type="text" name="Fish" placeholder="Field 4"/>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="submit"id="submit-form">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting a CORS error in the console?

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If so, I got it to work by changing the data type from 'json' to 'jsonp'. Also, the success part of the AJAX request should be inside the object.

```
$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: $form.serializeObject(),
    success: function() {
      console.log('it worked')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work when I click the submit button the error ```Did not load script at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwoNkRscUxkp7bOdHx3pPwj4D2doLATbgqEYKOoaIRFXCdRPlM/exec?callback=jQuery31106050297388535439_1513880634404&Groceries=100&Diary=100&Meat=100&Fish=100&_=1513880634405' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given.```

Comment: Where is your request coming from? From node or from a browser? I did mine from the browser in codepen.io. The 'jsonp' dataType overcomes CORS problems for browser requests, but not for server side requests.

Comment: I am running the request in chrome.  It will not execute the script and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

*unfortunately that did not work when I click the submit button the error Did not load script at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwoNkRscUxkp7bOdHx3‌​pPwj4D2doLATbgqEYKOo‌​aIRFXCdRPlM/exec?cal‌​lback=jQuery31106050‌​297388535439_1513880‌​634404&Groceries=100‌​&Diary=100&Meat=100&‌​Fish=100&_=151388063‌​4405' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given*

The above issue can be solved by adding the below code in you doget function -

```
function doGet(e) {

  // do whatever this webapp is for
  var result = doSomething(e); 
  // prepare the result
  var s = JSON.stringify(result);
  // publish result
  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(result.params.callback ? result.params.callback + "(" + s + ")" : s )
    .setMimeType(result.params.callback ? ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT : ContentService.MimeType.JSON); 
}
```